# Are there any friendly draugr?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I recently made a draugr build (an old blind guy) named Dinok-Drog ("Death Lord" in dragon language), and was wondering if there was a friendly neighborhood crypt I could join.

Comment: Sorry, role-playing questions don't really fit on our site. There's lots of opinions on how you can play the game, but in the end, only you can decide what to do.

Comment: He's asking about whether there is a friendly crypt in the game. I don't believe that's a role playing question, even if RP is the reason behind it.

Comment: Nothing comes to mind, no. I’ve been in quite a few draugr-inhabited ruins, any can’t recall and of the draugr being peaceful. It would be cool though. Also, this in-game book may interest you, if you haven’t read it already: [Amongst the Draugr](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Amongst_the_Draugr)

Comment: Thank you Amaranth do you happen to know where to find that book

Answer (score 6):

[This mod](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/18680/?) seems to be helpful, but I'm sure there's another more specific mod out there. But as regards in the vanilla game, while the game does randomly glitch out and produce friendly Draugr, there are none in the base game, even Legendary Edition.